# card reader falls off in linux

Tags: linux, sd-card

I have debian 11 and a MicroSd card reader built into my laptop. Device: Realtek Semiconductor RTS5129 Card Reader Controller. The problem is that it falls off after I insert the card and take it out several times for no apparent reason. There are no errors in the log.

I have tried commands like this:

```
modprobe -r rtsx_usb_sdmmc rtsx_usb_ms rtsx_usb
modprobe rtsx_usb_sdmmc rtsx_usb_ms rtsx_usb
```

After that I see it in the log:

```
Mar 07 21:42:20 linux kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver rtsx_usb
Mar 07 21:42:20 linux kernel: rtsx_usb_sdmmc: unknown parameter 'rtsx_usb_ms' ignored
Mar 07 21:42:20 linux kernel: rtsx_usb_sdmmc: unknown parameter 'rtsx_usb' ignored
```

I insert a memory card and Linux does not see it and in fdisk -l.

After restarting the computer, I can use the card again, help someone with what they can

Answer (score 1):

Can't help you with the card reader. Sounds like a firmware failure, which the windows driver probably silently works around by secretly resetting the device firmware.

I can help you with your `modprobe` errors:

```
modprobe -r rtsx_usb_sdmmc rtsx_usb_ms rtsx_usb
```

works, because `modprobe -r` can take multiple module names on one command line. Look at `man modprobe`:

```
modprobe [-r] [-v] [-n] [-i] [modulename...]
```

But

```
modprobe rtsx_usb_sdmmc rtsx_usb_ms rtsx_usb
```

fails, because modprobe syntax is (again, from `man modprobe`):

```
modprobe [modulename] [module parameters...]
```

"rtsx_usb_ms" and "rtsx_usb" are interpreted as *parameters* to `rtsx_usb_sdmmc`.

Instead, do

```bsh
modules="rtsx_usb_sdmmc rtsx_usb_ms rtsx_usb"
modprobe -r $modules
for mod in $modules ; do modprobe $mod ; done
```